# Finding frequency from phasor in EM wave

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, frequency

Here’s a homework question from my class on electromagnetism:

> The electric field phasor is $\mathbf E = E_0[3\cos x\sin2y,\enspace 6\sin x\cos2y,\enspace j\,5\sin x\sin2y]e^{-3jz}\,$.
>
> What is the frequency $f$, where $f=\omega/2\pi\,$?

From looking in the lecture notes and on Google, it seems like there is no way to determine frequency when given a phasor, but I'm wondering if there is some way that the $x$, $2y$ and $3z$ are related that ends up allowing the frequency to be solved for?

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to Physics.SE! It appears that you’ve read the homework guidance... And that’s awesome! Just a friendly comment: the guidelines are not there because we’re all evil, they’re there to help you ask a question that would be useful to other people. For the same reason, if you have a good question (and this is one), just go ahead and ask: _you don’t have to explain yourself_, or even say thanks; such things will usually be deleted from your question anyway because they distract from, well, the question :) Again, congrats on getting it right on the first try!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You’d say that there is no way to get the frequency of a harmonic oscillation from its phasor... And you’d be correct, because the very thing that distinguishes harmonic oscillations from nonlinear ones is that the frequency stays the same no matter the amplitude (and the initial phase is irrelevant in any autonomous system due to time-translation symmetry).

However, you’re right that those $x$s and $y$s change that. What you have here is not a *single* harmonic oscillation with a *single* phasor, but an *independent* oscillation and thus a *different* phasor *at each point in space*. In other words, an electromagnetic *wave*.

Now those oscillations aren’t exactly independent: values of $\mathbf E$ at different points influence each other according to the EM field equations—this is what causes the oscillations in the first place. In particular, this means there could be a relationship between the shape of an EM wave in space at a given moment and how it changes over time. Do you know of such a relationship?

Comment: I just realized I have the Helmholtz equation which relates E and beta where beta is defined from permittivity, permeability, and frequency.  So I can solve for beta here.  I don't know the relationship you are talking about though.

Comment: @Erik Well, there’s only one equation in all of this, so yes, the Helmhotz equation is one way of putting it. Even the wave equation itself would work: if you look closely at $\partial^2\mathbf E/\partial t^2 = \nabla^2\mathbf E$, you’ll see that there’s something about change in time at a single point on the left and something about the shape around that point at a single moment on the right. There’s your relationship.

Comment: The Helmholtz equation, of course, is the same thing with the dependence on time presupposed to be harmonic, $\propto e^{j\omega t}$. But your question presupposes a harmonic dependence on time in any case, so you could use either. (I’ve omitted the transmission medium business throughout because I’m lazy, but that’s only OK if its characteristics don’t depend on frequency in the range you care about—otherwise you only have Helmhotz.)

Comment: Ah yes he sort of breezed by the wave equation and went straight to time harmonic cases. And yes it was assumed to be a simple medium so the characteristics are constant.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The general form of a phasor discribing a plane wave (spherical, cylindrical or Cartesian) travelling in the direction 
$\hat n$ is
$$
\vec E_p=\vec E_0(x,y,z) e^{-jk\hat n\cdot \vec r}
$$
where $\vec E_0(x,y,z)\cdot\hat n=0$.  The amplitude need not be constant: in the case of a spherical wave it would go like $1/r$ for $\hat n=\hat r$ for instance.  Your proposed wave does not satisfy this orthogonality condition since clearly $\hat n=\hat z$ but your electric field has a $\hat z$ component, so something’s not quite right with your original homework question or the way your posted it or the way I understand it.

Still... continuing we have that the length $k$ of the wavevector 
$\vec k=k\hat n$ contains information about the frequency since
$$
v=\frac{\omega}{k}
$$
where $v$ is the phase velocity in the medium.  As the phase velocity is $v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu\epsilon}}$, with $\epsilon$ and $\mu$ the electric and magnetic constants of the propagating medium, you can find the information you need. In your specific case, $k=3$ and there is no dispersive effects as there is no exponential attenuation, so $\mu$ and $\epsilon$ are both real and that enough to determine $\omega$ if you know $\mu$ and $\epsilon$.